# how do I reconfigure loading position of a custom keypad as user scrolls down iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a tip calculator that uses a custom made keypad for number input. I have it set up to come into the screen at the bottom of the screen based off of screen size. Code below:

```
-(void)PreTaxTotalShowKeyPad
{

CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
//  CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;

[UIView beginAnimations:@"animateView" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
CGRect keypadViewiPhone = CGRectMake(0,(screenHeight -350),320,277);
PreTaxTotaliPhoneKeypadView.frame = keypadViewiPhone;
PreTaxTotaliPhoneKeypadView.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

The prob I have is that if you scroll down a bit and click the textbox to bring it back up it loads mush higher then I want it and is not visually pleasing.

I now realize (not sure how i missed it) that since I use a scroller view, when the user scrolls down the screen-size of course remains the same yet the distance from the top of the scroll view changes.

I looked everywhere and cant seem to figure out how to programmically get the cord for the bottom of the screen window to the top of the scroll view.

in essence changing the code

```
CGRect keypadViewiPhone = CGRectMake(0,(screenHeight -350),320,277);
```

to

```
CGRect keypadViewiPhone = CGRectMake(0,( distanceFromTopOfScrollViewToBottomOfScreen - 350),320,277);
```

so that way it loads up in the correct position no matter where you are (and can be used to scroll with the page too)